Django rest session authentification postman
I've customised django auth method:
class MyBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, phone=None, otp=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(phone=phone)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.otp == otp:
                # user.otp = None
                # user.save()
                return user

    def get_user(self, phone):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(phone=phone)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None

My authentication class:
class ValidateOTP(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        phone = request.data.get('phone', None)
        otp = request.data.get('otp', None)

        if not phone or not otp:
            return Response({'error': 'Wrong data.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        user = authenticate(request, phone=phone, otp=otp)
        login(request, user)
        return Response({'Ok': 'ok'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

With postman I create user by endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/validate-otp/ . Everything is ok.
But when I try to GET request to another endpoint, my request.user is Anonymous.
class UserInfo(APIView):
    permission_classes = ([IsAuthenticated])
    def get(self, request):
        print(request.user)
        return Response({'ok': 'ok'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

What can be a problem?
UPD (1):
class ValidateOTP(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, ]
    
    def post(self, request):
        phone = request.data.get('phone', None)
        otp = request.data.get('otp', None)

        if not phone or not otp:
            return Response({'error': 'Wrong data.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        user = authenticate(request, phone=phone, otp=otp)
        login(request, user)
        return Response({'Token': 'token.key'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class UserInfo(APIView):
    permission_classes = ([IsAuthenticated])
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication,]

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.select_related('referral_code').get(pk=request.user.id)
        serialized = UserSerializer(queryset)
        return Response({'ok': serialized.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


loign(request, user) often does not make much sense in an API: you each tiem send the token, and each APIView needs the authentication class to attach the user on the reques.t

A login(…) [Django-doc] in an API (often) does not make much sense. Unless you use the SessionAuthentication [drf-doc] or implement some session-like authentication yourself. The login is attached to that session, but the next HTTP request, does not use that session: if you would work with session-based authentication, you each time need to send the session id with the request.
Authentication like OTP thus should return for example a token the client can then use for (every) request, or perhaps change of the token, or work with a session id, but a user login thus logs in the user for that session, so if you use that, you will need the API and the client to be aware of the session.

Thx for answer!
Yep, after auth I received sessionid in cookies postman. Should I include this value in hedders?

@Андрей: you should include it in the Cookie you send back in the next request, furthermore that APIView will need SessionAuthentication as auth backend.

Okay, I've added in headers SESSION_KEY, and SessionAuthentication as authentication_classes . But it doesn't work(. Postman forward received cookies automatically.

@Андрей: can you edit the question with the updated APIViews, authentication, etc.?
